# New to Ubuntu-Can't find panel and other problems?

Tags: vmware, panel

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtual machine (VMware to be precise), and all I have is a desktop. I've managed to create a new folder and document, but I can't move windows, access the panel/taskbar, or open anything besides file explorer and system settings. I have no taskbar/clock, ctrl+alt+tab and ctrl+alt+t don't open command lines, I've adjusted where to mouse over for sidebar to appear and that hasn't helped...I pretty much have a 20GB desktop background that can save files.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may have to mess with the settings in VMWare, usually sending ctl,alt,super,win keys needs to be configured to be sent to virtual machine (versus host machine).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :) I seem to have already done that, but I've noticed one weird thing-on the login screen, I have the clock and menu bar...but it vanishes after accepting the password. And after rebooting in the VM, I've received an error that it "could not apply the stored configuration for monitors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by OP in question box (since edited out):

> For some reason VMWare expedites the installation process for Ubuntu, skipping over region selection, log-in setup and related items. I'm willing to be this is why everything's missing, because it only did a half install. I switched to VirtualBox and have no problems.

Comment: For future reference, how do I make an official answer/accept one? Or is that only through a mod's job?

Comment: Okay, at the bottom is a button - click Answer your Question (https://imgur.com/uFNERib), then OK and then type it in. However, don't do that to add more details, use the edit button as you did :-). Just so you know, I'm not a mod ;-) I just have more privileges because of my score (3216)